# How to write OpenAPI 3.0 for this responseBody?

Tags: openapi

I'm attempting to manually create an OpenAPI definition for a REST interface that I want to call (they provided me with an example payload).

```json
{
  "Accounts": [
    {
      "ID": "",
      "Name": "testIDMissing",
      "Sales Force Active Status": "False",
      "Sales Force Type": "Prospect",
      "Sales Force Cost Center": "9938 ICP/DCO/Regional",
      "FNC SAP Sold To Number": ""
    },
    {
      "ID": "001345340017Hvk3A7C",
      "Name": "Project Performance Group create",
      "Sales Force Active Status": "True",
      "Sales Force Type": "Integrator",
      "Sales Force Cost Center": "9995 Channels",
      "FNC SAP Sold To Number": "18815"
    },
    {
      "ID": "00134535017Hvk3AAC",
      "Name": "Project Performance Group Update",
      "Sales Force Active Status": "True",
      "Sales Force Type": "Integrator",
      "Sales Force Cost Center": "9999",
      "FNC SAP Sold To Number": "99"
    },
    {
      "ID": "NoName",
      "Name": "",
      "Sales Force Active Status": "",
      "Sales Force Type": "",
      "Sales Force Cost Center": "",
      "FNC SAP Sold To Number": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I've got this:

```yaml
  requestBody:
    description: Account Objects
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Accounts'
  ...

components:
  schemas:
    Accounts:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Account'
      example: 
        - ID:1
          Name:testIDMissing
          Sales Force Active Status:False
          Sales Force Type:Prospect
          Sales Force Cost Center:9938 ICP/DCO/Regional
          FNC SAP Sold To Number:1111
        - ID:2
          Name:anotherExample
          Sales Force Active Status:True
          Sales Force Type:Prospect
          Sales Force Cost Center:9937 ICP/DCO/Regional
          FNC SAP Sold To Number:2222
    Account:
      type: object
      properties:
        ID:
          type: string
          description: Account ID in SFDC
        Sales Force Active Status:
          type: string
          description: Is Account Active
          enum:
          - False
          - True
        Sales Force Type:
          type: string
        Sales Force Cost Center:
          type: string
        FNC SAP Sold To Number:
          type: string
      xml:
        name: Account
```

Which gets me close. Postman generates the example like this:

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "<string>",
    "Sales Force Active Status": "<string>",
    "Sales Force Type": "<string>",
    "Sales Force Cost Center": "<string>",
    "FNC SAP Sold To Number": "<string>"
  },
  {
    "ID": "<string>",
    "Sales Force Active Status": "<string>",
    "Sales Force Type": "<string>",
    "Sales Force Cost Center": "<string>",
    "FNC SAP Sold To Number": "<string>"
  }
]
```

It seems I'm pretty close. I'm not sure what I need to add or how to define the `Accounts` object to get it correct.

Comment: The ^^ linked questions are about OpenAPI 2.0, but the idea is the same - you need to wrap the `Accounts` schema into another schema that is an object with the `Accounts` property.

Comment: By the way, you need to add quotes around `"True"` and `"False"`, otherwise they are parsed as boolean values instead of strings.

Comment: Ahhhh. I had the correct idea, I just needed to wrap it with another 'parent'

Comment: Also add spaces after `:` in examples: `ID: '1'`, `Name: testIDMissing`, etc.